# MySQL is there a way to check if a string is present in a field before update it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my code:

```
mysql.query("INSERT INTO CategorieItems (productid, title, image, rating, price, reviews, nodes) 
            VALUES ? 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            title=VALUES(title), image=VALUES(image), rating=VALUES(rating), price=VALUES(price), reviews=VALUES(reviews), nodes = CONCAT(IFNULL(nodes, ''), CONCAT(' - ', nodes))", 
        [itemArray]);
```

I'm scraping a website, it saves all infos in my mysql database, right now my query code check if  productid is already in my database, if it exist already it updates all field overwriting current data, except nodes field because I've added a concat function, so it adds new nodes everytime the item is queried.
My issue is that if the items is fetched twice in the same node in my database I find something like "Node1 - Node2 - Node2 - Node 3". So in this example Node2 is present twice, is it possible to check if Node2 is already present and if exists don't write it again.

Comment: The best solution is to not store lists in a column like that. They should be separate rows in another table that's linked to this table by a foreign key.

Comment: I assume the missing `VALUES(nodes)` is a copying error.

Comment: @Barmar I'm very new to mysql and database world in general, just a stupid question, so the best thing is to basically create a new table with 2 fields, product id and node, performance wise 2 queries instead of one is a big issue? In the new table would you check if productid and node matches or just write them and handle duplicates afterwards? Thank you for your replies!

Comment: You would make `(product_id, node)` a unique index in the new table, so that duplicates are not possible.

Comment: Foreign keys are always indexed, so the performance impact should be small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you normalized your design. Barring that, the best you can do is search the column for a match:

```
nodes = IF(LOCATE(VALUES(nodes), nodes), 
            nodes, 
            CONCAT(IFNULL(nodes, ''), ' - ', VALUES(nodes)))
```

This is not very robust because it will also match if the new node is a substring of one of the existing nodes.